# Copy Table Data From Local To Remote Location

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

```
COPY FROM DBO_TEST/DBO_TEST -
TO ORA_DEV/ORA_DEV -
CREATE SAMPLE2 -
USING SELECT * FROM SAMPLE1 where rownum<=100;
```

When I execute the above query I'm getting the error as "connection failed".
Is the query is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`COPY` is SQL*Plus command. For it's clauses `FROM` and `TO` you have to specify source or destination database you wish to COPY FROM or COPY TO in format: `username[/password]@connect_identifier`.

If you do not specify password in either the COPY FROM clause or the COPY TO clause, SQL*Plus will prompt you for it.

`connect_identifier` part is obligatory and seem not to be provided in your example.

For more information check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a90842/apb.htm